# Preventing Web.config inheritance on <sectionGroup>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, web-config

I have been looking for a solution to this for a while but can not find one anywhere...

**Background:** I have two web applications; one is running Umbraco CMS, this is the root web app. The second is an MVC 4 application and is a **Virtual Directory** within the root app i.e. /rootapp/quote.

Each app has its own Web.config. Initially I had issues with config inheritance but I resolved this (nearly) by placing using the `<location>` tag within the parent app config like so:

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
   ....
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This fixed the errors but generated a fresh one which I can't fix.. I understand it's because the parent Web.config has already defined Razor.

I have tried `<remove name="system.web.webPages.razor"/>` within the sub app with no luck, any ideas how to block inheritance..?

**Error**

```
Line 3:  <configuration>
Line 4:    <configSections>
Line 5:      <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
Line 6:        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
Line 7:        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the Nature of the beast.
My question is whether or not you could modify your deployment so that the quote app was not inside of your root:

```
Url 1: http://server/root/cms

Url 2: http://server/root/quote
```

Then configure IIS to redirect any requests to /root to /root/cms

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because (apparently) Umbraco doesn't allow this by design. I guess it's possible but would be hacky.